# How to set Android background music playing only one time

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am creating a game, I want to play a background music for one activity only(For main menu of game), my code shown below, The problem is that the music plays more than one time, I want to play the same music also when activity Resumes.

```
public class Menu extends Activity {
   MediaPlayer mp
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(Menu.this, R.raw.adalante);
    if(!mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.start();
    }
public void play(View ButtonClicked) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    //mp = MediaPlayer.create(Menu.this, R.raw.l);
    //mp.start();
    goToActivity(Game.class);
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
    //coins
    coin.setText(data.getString("coin"));
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Menu.this, R.raw.adalante);
    if(!mp.isPlaying()) {

        mp.start();
    }

    //mps.release();

}
```

Comment: in your onResume method before  initializing mp = MediaPlayer.create(Menu.this, R.raw.adalante); put a check if its null only then create a new object

Answer (score 1):

In your onResume don't initialise MediaPlayer again and again. It creates new instance every time when you come to onResume. So add a check in onResume like this :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mp==null)
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.adalante);

    if (!mp.isPlaying())
        mp.start();
}
```

and additionally add this for prevention to play when activity goes to onPause

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mp.pause();
}
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                           at android.media.MediaPlayer._pause(Native Method)

Comment: When it occurs?

Comment: After pressing play button

Comment: k. here do one thing. take a global variable in activity like this `boolean mIsPlayerRelease = false;` and then in play method add this `mIsPlayerRelease=true;` and in onPause add this `if (!mIsPlayerRelease&&mp.isPlaying())` before  mp.pause()